# How to iterate through all the ENV variables printing key and value?

Tags: bash

I'd like to iterate through the variables in [`env`](http://ss64.com/bash/env.html) printing:

```
name: ${name} value: ${value}
```

Simply splitting by line break and iterating does not work, because of multi-line values, e.g.

```
SERVER_TLS_SERVER_CRT=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
foo
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The use case is to workaround [Docker limitation](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12997) that restricts passing multi-line variables via `--env-file`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the solution from #bash.

```
unset IFS
args=() i=0
for var in $(compgen -e); do
    printf -v 'args[i++]' -e%s=%s "$var" "${!var}"
done
```

I initially thought the idea was to output, hence printf %q was necessary, but that's not the case when just building an arguments array, so it can be simplified to this:

```
unset IFS
args=()
for var in $(compgen -e); do
    args+=( "-e$var=${!var}" )
done
```

Comment: This answer is correct but does not append the result into `args`.  
Remove the brackets to solve and append to the string. Thanks anyway for the solution. 

Replace:  
`args+=( "-e$var=${!var}" ) `

with:
`args+="-e$var=${!var}"`

Comment: @roest That really is how you append to an array, but you must use `"${args[@]}"` to expand it. `"$args"` would only expand the first entry of the array.

Comment: `bad variable name: unset: IFS`

Comment: @Saibamen that does not look like an error message from bash

Answer (score 18):

You can use `env -0` to get a null terminated list of `name=value` pairs and use a for loop to iterate:

```
while IFS='=' read -r -d '' n v; do
    printf "'%s'='%s'\n" "$n" "$v"
done < <(env -0)
```

Above script use *process substitution*, which is a BASH feature. On older shells you can use a pipeline:

```
env -0 | while IFS='=' read -r -d '' n v; do
    printf "'%s'='%s'\n" "$n" "$v"
done
```

Comment: I have seen this snipped in another thread. It gives a syntax error, ``./foo.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `<'\n ./foo.sh: line 3: `done < <(env -0)'``

Comment: That is because you're not using `bash`. Make sure you are using `bash` to execute your script. Or else use:  `env -0 | while IFS='=' read -r -d '' n v; do printf '{ "name": "%s", "value": "%s" }\n' "$n" "$v"; done` that avoids process substitution.

Comment: This solution seems to require GNU extensions to `env`. With a BSD-based `env` (for example, on Mac), `/usr/bin/env -0` and `env -0` both report that `-0` is an illegal option.

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to remove the `-0` from `env` and `-d ''` from read? The following works for me in `BusyBox` and `Bash`:
`env | while IFS='=' read -r n v; do  printf "'%s'='%s'\n" "$n" "$v"; done
`

Comment: @langfingaz: It will work as long as there no newlines in the value of the env variable

Comment: `Syntax error: "done" unexpected (expecting "do")`

Comment: @Saibamen: That means you're not using `bash`

Comment: `env -0` doesn't work for me, `env | xxx` works. However, with the pipeline I have problem with constructing a string by concatenating the values as it's being run in a sub-shell the outer variable remains unchanged. FYI, I am trying to construct a JSON string from certain env variables to later write it into a file. Any way to get around this issue?

Comment: You need to use gnu version of `env` to use `-0` option

Comment: POSIX `read` does not support `-d`.

Answer (score 11):

Old thread, I know.
But for anyone else needing a solution in sh and without -0 support for env:

```
env | while IFS= read -r line; do
  value=${line#*=}
  name=${line%%=*}
  echo "V: $value"
  echo "N: $name"
done
```

Comment: `syntax error near unexpected token done'`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Bash's `compgen` or `export -p` or POSIX's `env` do not structure their output, making its parsing vulnerable to misinterpretation.  Other languages reading their POSIX-provided list of environment variables can fill the gap.

```
jq -n 'env'
```

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html

As for "writing" this to a Docker container, just passing the value on the command line works.  (I see comments to [a Docker issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12997) on a new flag to keep existing usage backwards-compatible).

```
$ lf=$'\n'

$ export foobar="first line${lf} space prefixed${lf}space terminated ${lf}last line"

$ docker run --rm --read-only -e "foobar" bash -c 'while IFS= read -r line; do echo "<<${line}>>"; done <<< "${foobar}"'
<<first line>>
<< space prefixed>>
<<space terminated >>
<<last line>>
```