# Post all environment variables to endpoint with curl

Tags: php, linux, curl

small question for curl experts :-)

This PHP script returns all the data they get.
I want that each environment variable is a post parameter and the value is the post value.

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_REQUEST);
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

This is the CURL command I'm using.

```
printenv | curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost/test.php --data-binary @-
```

And this is the output.

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
string(1894) "XDG_SESSION_ID=199191
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
SSH_CLIENT=127.0.0.1 4318 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/root/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
PWD=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
SSH_CONNECTION=127.0.0.1 22
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/printenv
"
```

And I expect this.

```
Array
(
    XDG_SESSION_ID => 199191
    TERM => xterm
    SHELL => /bin/bash
    SSH_CLIENT => 127.0.0.1 4318 22
    SSH_TTY => /dev/pts/0
    USER => root
    LS_COLORS => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
    MAIL => /var/mail/root
    PATH => /root/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
    PWD => /root
    LANG => en_US.UTF-8
    SHLVL => 1
    HOME => /root
    LOGNAME => root
    SSH_CONNECTION => 127.0.0.1 22
    LESSOPEN => | /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR => /run/user/0
    LESSCLOSE => /usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
    _ => /usr/bin/printenv
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
string(0) ""
```

Comment: well, the output of `printenv` is not JSON encoded, and you are specifying `Content-type: application/json` in the `curl(1)` command.... It's normal you are getting something wrong, input is not JSON encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Form encoded

Use `tr` to replace new line with `&` :

```
printenv | tr '\n' '&' | curl "http://localhost/test.php" -d @-
```

The command above will not work well with new line, `=` and `&` in variable names

To deal with these case, you can url encode all the values :

```
# from Chris Down https://gist.github.com/cdown/1163649
urlencode() {
    # urlencode <string>
    old_lc_collate=$LC_COLLATE
    LC_COLLATE=C

    local length="${#1}"
    for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do
        local c="${1:i:1}"
        case $c in
            [a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]) printf "$c" ;;
            *) printf '%%%02X' "'$c" ;;
        esac
    done

    LC_COLLATE=$old_lc_collate
}

# from anubhava https://stackoverflow.com/a/39529897/2614364
while IFS='=' read -r -d '' n v; do
    printf "%s=%s\n" "$n" $(urlencode "$v")
done < <(env -0) | tr '\n' '&' | curl "http://localhost/test.php" -d @-
```

The above script uses :

- https://gist.github.com/cdown/1163649 from Chris Down to url encode
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39529897/2614364 from anubhava to list key/value

PHP output :

```
print_r($_POST);
```

#### JSON

You can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON parser to build a JSON document matching the format `field=value` linefeed delimited :

```
printenv | jq -sR  'split("\n") | map(split("=")) | 
              map(select(length > 0) | { (.[0]) : (.[1:] | join("")) }) | add'
```

With the curl request :

```
printenv | jq -sR  'split("\n") | map(split("=")) | 
              map(select(length > 0) | { (.[0]) : (.[1:] | join("")) }) | add' | \
           curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
           "http://localhost/test.php" --data-binary @-
```

For the jq part :

- `split("\n")` build a JSON array with each lines as values
- `map(split("="))` make arrays with items splitted according to `=`
- `map(select(length > 0)` take care of empty array
- `{ (.[0]) : (.[1:] | join("")) })` map key/value according to array items (as there can be more than 2 items in values that contains `=`, its necessary to join the remaining items from 1 to the end)

PHP output :

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Ok with `apt install jq` it'll work. But maybe there is another solution which not need `jq`. I tought it is possible to send this directly via `curl`. I thought for send a POST request its defined similar: `curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" https://example.com/resource.cgi` So Why its not possible with this `printenv` :-( But thank you very much. I can continue work with your script :-)

Comment: I thought you explicitly wanted JSON format by setting content type as `application/json`, I've added form encoded solution which is more simple

Comment: Oh sorry :-( I copied this from somewhere else. I not need JSON. Your solution works really perfect. But if I have a environment variable which contains an `=` character with multiple lines it's not working anymore. Currently I have no variables with multiple lines and `=` in it. But maybe in future or for other peoples it could be interested. But really thank you very much <3

`export ASD="1=23
45
==123
A=B
as
"`

`    [ASD] => 1=23
    [45] =>
    [A] => B
    [as] =>
`

Comment: Please see my updated post which will url encode values to deal with special characters

Comment: <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 Thank you more than very much :-) You saved my week ;-)