# How to transform the output of a command in a list of arguments in BASH?

Tags: bash, shell

there

I need to pass multiple arguments to a `docker` command, but I wanted this string of arguments to be built interactively and not by hand. In my specific problem, I want to get all the environment variables in this machine and set each one of them as a `build-arg` argument.

For example, if the env variables are

```
ENV_VAR1=ENV_VALUE1
ENV_VAR2=ENV_VALUE2
ENV_VAR3=ENV_VALUE3
```

I want to build a string like this

```
docker build --build-arg ENV_VAR1=ENV_VALUE1 --build-arg ENV_VAR2=ENV_VALUE2 --build-arg ENV_VAR1=ENV_VALUE1 .`
```

I was wondering how to wrap this repetition in a bash script something like this (please this is just a pseudocode):

```
docker build $(FOREACH get_output_of_env() AS $env DO `--build-arg $env` END) .
```

Is that anyhow possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does the output from `GET_OUTPUT_OF_ENV` look like? do you have to worry about any of the env values containing white space or non-alphanumerics?

Comment: i guess some of them will have white spaces, yes. most won't. `GET_OUTPUT_OF_ENV` would get the output of `env` command and assign it to a list, line by line, for example.

Comment: considering updating your question with a) what `GET_OUTPUT_OF_ENV` consists of, b) example output from `GET_OUTPUT_OF_ENV` (preferably some examples with embedded white space) and c) the desired output (given the sample input)

Comment: my friend, `GET_OUTPUT_OF_ENV` is just an example, because I had to write something before the loop. This could be rewritten like this `FOREACH getOutputOfEnv() as $env DO --build-arg $env END`. the desired output is in the question already. I will update the question, see if it helps

Answer (score 2):

Use an array:

```
dockerargs=()
for i in ENV_VAR1 ENV_VAR2 ENV_VAR3; do
     dockerargs+=(--build-arg "$i=${!i}")
done
docker build "${dockerargs[@]}" ...
```

If you really want to use [how to iterate over env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529648/how-to-iterate-through-all-the-env-variables-printing-key-and-value) and do `for i in $(compgen -e)`

Comment: the problem is that I dont want to (and sometimes i cant) write each one of them like that. this is why getting the output of a command and transforming it into a list, makes it better

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

cat > args < EOF
#!/bin/sh
EOF
env -0 >> args
sed -i s'@^@--build-arg @g' args
tr '\n' ' '
sed -i s'@^@docker build@' args
```

Then just execute "args" as another shell script.  I admit that I haven't tested this, but I can't see too many reasons why it shouldn't work.

Comment: This will fail in unexpected ways if any of the variables contains a whitespace.

Comment: Which many of them presumably will.  Should I delete this solution do you think, or is there a way to fix it?

Comment: `Should I delete this solution do you think` No idea, up to you :p `is there a way to fix it?` Well, `env -0`, then for each line extract variable name, quote the variable properly with with `printf "%q"` and join and add `--build-arg`